# Unable to send email inside my CSOM console application inside our office 365 sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, office-365, client-object-model, csom

I have the following code as part of a console application:-

```
            using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(scurl))
            {
                string s = "***the password***";
                SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
                foreach (var cc in s)
                passWord.AppendChar(cc);
                context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("admin.user@*****.onmicrosoft.com", passWord);    
                List oList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listname);
                CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
                camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='ContractReviewDate'/>" +
                "<Value Type='DateTime'><Today /></Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='ContractStatus'/><Value Type='String'>Active</Value></Eq></AND></Where></Query><RowLimit>5000</RowLimit></View>";
                ListItemCollection collListItem = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);
                context.Load(collListItem,
                items => items.Include(
                item => item["ContractStatus"],
                item => item["PersonResponsible"]));
                context.ExecuteQuery();
                foreach (ListItem oListItem in collListItem)
                {
                    oListItem["ContractStatus"] = "Needs Review";
                    oListItem.Update();
                    context.ExecuteQuery();
                    var userValue =  (FieldUserValue)oListItem["PersonResponsible"];
                    var user = context.Web.GetUserById(userValue.LookupId);
                    context.Load(user, x => x.Email);
                    context.ExecuteQuery();
                    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("no-reply@sharepointonline.com", user.Email);
                    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
                    client.Port = 587;
                    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    client.EnableSsl = true;
                    client.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
                    mail.Subject = "The Contract has revowed";
                    mail.Body = "this is my test email body";
                    client.Send(mail);
                }

            }
```

but i am getting exception on `client.Send(mail);`, as follow:-

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException was unhandled   HResult=-2146233088
>   Message=Failure sending mail.   Source=System   StackTrace:
>          at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
>          at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users***\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 77
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>          at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException: System.Net.WebException
>          HResult=-2146233079
>          Message=Unable to connect to the remote server
>          Source=System
>          StackTrace:
>               at System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream, Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket&
>   abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket6)
>               at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean async, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)
>               at System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32
>   creationTimeout)
>               at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint
>   servicePoint)
>               at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()
>               at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
>          InnerException: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
>               HResult=-2147467259
>               Message=No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 52.97.165.146:587
>               Source=System
>               ErrorCode=10061
>               NativeErrorCode=10061
>               StackTrace:
>                    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
>                    at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure,
>   Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address,
>   ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception&
>   exception)
>               InnerException:

so can anyone advice on this please?

Answer (score 1):

the way I see it, you are setting up a SMTPClient object but not supplying any credentials

so, either have set `client.UseDefaultCredentials` to true or use,

```
System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
client.Credentials = credentials;
```

or use csom utilities to send the email instead [PS code],

```
$EmailProperties = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.EmailProperties
$EmailProperties.From = $EmailFrom
$EmailProperties.To = [String[]] $EmailTo
$EmailProperties.Subject = $Subject
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.Utility]::SendEmail($Context,$EmailProperties)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
```

more

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766928/how-to-set-username-and-password-for-smtpclient-object-in-net

[Send Email from SharePoint Online using CSOM in PowerShell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/271521/send-email-from-sharepoint-online-using-csom-in-powershell)

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/how-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-office-3

Comment: ok thanks will try your approach, but will your proposed approach allow me to send emails to external users?